# RX: How to wait for subscribers to finish?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a producer which downloads data in pages from a Rest API and several consumers that process the pages (e.g. load them to a database).

I would like to have producer and consumers working in parallel, meaning that producer should not wait for a page to be consumed before downloading the next one. Each consumer needs to process pages sequentially.

When all pages are downloaded, the main thread should wait for all consumers to complete their work (as consuming may take longer than producing).

My current approach is as follows:

I have created an observable that downloads the pages, which starts as soon as consumer subscribers are attached. I configured the subscribers to observe on 
their own threads for parallel execution.

Code in C#:

```cs
IEnumerable<Page> getPages = produce();
var observable = getPages.ToObservable().Publish();

observable
   .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
   .Subscribe(page => consume1(page));

observable
   .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
   .Subscribe(page => consume2(page));

observable.Connect();
```

The problem with this implementation is that the main thread may finish before all pages are processed and the application stops.

How can I achieve this using RX?

Thanks!

Edit:

Tried also the following approach (from an answer):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var getPages = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

    var els1 = new EventLoopScheduler();
    var els2 = new EventLoopScheduler();

    var observable =
        getPages
            .ToObservable()
            .Publish(ps =>
                Observable
                    .Merge(
                        ps.Select(p => Observable.Start(() => consume1(p), els1)),
                        ps.Select(p => Observable.Start(() => consume2(p), els2))));

    observable.Wait();
}

public static void consume1(int p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"1:{p}");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}

public static void consume2(int p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"2:{p}");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

observable.Wait() returns as soon as underlying enumerable finishes yielding values. The output is:

```
1:0
2:0
```

Just to prove, if we replace getPages with:

```cs
var getPages = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Produced {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(30);
        return i;
    });
```

then the output is:

```
Produced 0
Produced 1
1:0
2:0
Produced 2
Produced 3
Produced 4
2:1
Produced 5
Produced 6
Produced 7
1:1
2:2
Produced 8
Produced 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
var els1 = new EventLoopScheduler();
var els2 = new EventLoopScheduler();

var observable =
    getPages
        .ToObservable()
        .Publish(ps =>
            Observable
                .Merge(
                    ps.SelectMany(p => Observable.Start(() => consume1(p), els1)),
                    ps.SelectMany(p => Observable.Start(() => consume2(p), els2))));
```

I wrote this test code:

```
var getPages = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

var els1 = new EventLoopScheduler();
var els2 = new EventLoopScheduler();

var observable =
    getPages
        .ToObservable()
        .Publish(ps =>
            Observable
                .Merge(
                    ps.SelectMany(p => Observable.Start(() => consume1(p), els1)),
                    ps.SelectMany(p => Observable.Start(() => consume2(p), els2))));

observable.Wait();

public void consume1(int p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"1:{p}");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}

public void consume2(int p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"2:{p}");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

I got this output:

```
1:0
2:0
2:1
1:1
2:2
2:3
1:2
2:4
2:5
1:3
2:6
2:7
1:4
2:8
2:9
1:5
1:6
1:7
1:8
1:9
```

When you've finished with the `EventLoopScheduler` instances you should call `.Dispose()` on them to close the threads.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately Wait() does not wait for consumers to finish and pages are not processed sequentially .

Comment: Any other ideas? This seems to be a pretty basic use case, though I'm unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not in my case - my output shows only two first lines. Perhaps this would be the same for you if you increased the sleep time.

Tested with System.Reactive versions 3.1.1 and 4.1.5.

Comment: @kra - Can you explain what you mean by it didn't work in your case? Did you try my sample code? Did it work as in my sample? How is your code different?

Comment: Sure. Yes, I tried your sample code and it worked differently; the main thread did not wait for the consumer threads to finish and application exited after displaying 1:0 2:0.

Comment: @kra - The `observable.Wait()` should halt the code. Can you please edit your question and add to the bottom exactly what you have tried? I'd like a [mcve] of your version of my code.

Comment: @kra - I got a `Select` wrong that should have been a `SelectMany`. Whoops. And It wasn't due to the enumerable completing - it was that the outer observable of `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>` produced the first value. Not that it is `IObservable<Unit>` it works fine.