# RxJava – how to wait for subscriber to process stream

Tags: java, rx-java

This is exactly the same problem as this:

[RX: How to wait for subscribers to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003010/rx-how-to-wait-for-subscribers-to-finish)

I have a producer which can produce object faster than subscriber so I want it to produce objects in parallel but block after some fixed number of items.

Like this:

1. publisher produces items
2. as soon as 10 items are produced, subscriber takes them and start processing
3. publisher continues to produce and buffer items in parallel, but if next 10 are produced, then it waits for subscriber
4. after finishing processing, subscriber immediately takes next 10 objects from the buffer
5. publisher continues to produce and buffer items
6. etc.

Current solution:

```java
            val bars = Flowable.fromStream(foos)
// calculate is faster
                    .map(foo -> calculateBars(foo))
                    .buffer(10)
// than saving to database
                    .flatMap(bars -> Flowable.fromStream(saveBars(bars)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                    .blockingGet();
```

If I add `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` then publisher doesn't wait at all for consumer and eventually crash with OutOfMemoryError. If I remove it it waits all the time instead of preparing the next batch of items.

This is related to my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73660953/keep-memory-usage-constant-with-jparepository-andrxjava . I think that solving this issue will solve that.

Comment: Not sure how you got OOM but the reason the two stages didn't run parallel is that in RxJava, sources may not run on the thread they were created. You have to use `subscribeOn` or another `observeOn` and sandwitch that `map` between them. So `fromStream` would not (and can't run) on the current thread.

Comment: I get OOM because publisher and subscriber run in parallel but subscriber don't wait for publisher to process a previous batch. I want them to run in parallel but publisher should stop if subscriber cannot catch up (as I described it in points 1-6).
Can you please provide an example of such solution (eg. using an infinite stream, sleep to simulate long calculate and a slightly longer sleep to simulate save)?

Comment: I've modified the part about "observeOn", that was a copy-paste error.

Comment: Flowable is there to prevent such OOM, however, you may need to tune the `maxConcurrency` and `prefetch` argument if you run in memory-constrainted environment. What you posted, with the observeOn confinement, should work so nothing to show on my part. Please provide a self-contained example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to implement this in java, I gave up and solved the problem with kotlin coroutines

```kotlin
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    open fun calculate(): Set<UUID> {
        val fooIds = findOperators()
        val saved = mutableListOf<UUID>()
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Run calculations in a separated thread, which communicates
            // with the main thread via a channel of batches.
            // Meanwhile, the main thread is busy saving records to database as soon as they arrive
            // from the calculation thread.
            val channel = Channel<Collection<Bar>>(1)
            launch {
                var batch = mutableListOf<Bar>()
                for (id in fooIds) {
                    val records = findRecordsByFoo(id)

                    if (batch.size == BATCH_SIZE) {
                        channel.send(batch)
                        batch = mutableListOf()
                    }
                }
                if (batch.isNotEmpty()) {
                    channel.send(batch)
                }
                try {
                    channel.close()
                }
                catch (e: ClosedReceiveChannelException) {
                    log.info("Finished processing foos")
                }
            }
            for (bars in channel) {
                val uuids = saveBars(bars)
                saved.addAll(uuids.asSequence())
            }
        }
        fooIds.close()
        return saved.toSet()
    }
```

Edit: These a required gradle changes:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.10'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
}
// to put the kotlin file close to a java service which calls it:
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}
```